# Locating nearby hospitals on google map in android

Tags: android

I am  trying to develop code for android..that shows nearby hospital locations to user's current location..I know this is possible only from kml file but i dont know how to do this. please please help me to solve this....

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar kind of problem.As i didn't get any good solution then i solved it in different way.So you can try this.You can store all the locations(latitude/longitude) for hospitals.Then from the current location(latitude/longitude) find out the distant of all hospitals.By sorting the distant you will find nearest hospital.

Comment: How you can find the longitide,latitude of nearest hospitals?

Comment: You can find it directly from map or by reverse geocoding.You have to find it anyway and have to store it so that you can use it.

Comment: I know its too late to answer but try google places API, especially google search api provides the placetypes location which can be shown on map.